# Angular Material DatePicker date.toLocaleDateString is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am attempting to use the angular-material date picker and am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: date.toLocaleDateString is not a function
at Object.defaultFormatDate [as formatDate] (angular-material.js:6860)
at DatePickerCtrl.configureNgModel.ngModelCtrl.$render (angular-material.js:7184)
at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:25233)
at m.a.$get.m.$digest (angular.js:15707)
at m.a.$get.m.$apply (angular.js:15986)
at g (angular.js:10511)
at L (angular.js:10683)
at XMLHttpRequest.A.onload (angular.js:10624)
```

I haave taken the example from the code pen here:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.input

The relevant HTML Code:

```
            <div layout="" layout-sm="column">
            <md-input-container style="width:70%">
                <label>Company (Disabled)</label>
                <input ng-model="user.company" disabled="">
            </md-input-container>

            <md-datepicker ng-model="date" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
        </div>
```

My Controller

```
$scope.date={};
$scope.$watch('date', function () {
    console.log($scope.date);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

toLocaleDateString is a native method of a date object, so it appears that your md-datepicker is not bound to a date. Without the HTML and the code that populates your data, it's hard to tell for sure, but that's the most likely reason.

Comment: You were correct. I had not set the ng-model of the date picker to a valid javascript date in my controller and on scope. THANK YOU!!! I will edit my question for this to make more sense for others.

Answer (score 0):

Quite possibly your `date` object is not of type `Date`, make sure it is of that type only, not `string` or something else.

This is why I got this problem, and how I solved it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

i have face this error because i'm trying to assign format string value to a model which is bind with md-datepicker which is hold javascript date type
like this

```
$scope.eventdate = $filter('date')($scope.eventdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

the solution is declare new model for md-datepicker and get its value like this

on js

```
$scope.eventdate = $filter('date')($scope.mddate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

on html

```
 <md-datepicker ng-model="mddate" md-placeholder="Enter date" required></md-datepicker>
```

hope this can help you

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem, but the answers above did not help.

Initialising the datepicker with new Date() worked, but when attempting to initialise with value returned from the server I got the error above - despite them seemingly being in the same format.

In the end I had to explicitly create a Date object and then set it's value using Parse.

```
        var date = ctrl.data.fromServer;
        ctrl.data.fromServer= new Date();
        if (date != undefined)
        {
            ctrl.data.fromServer.setTime(Date.parse(date));
        }
```

Comment: Yes, your server returns text. You have to explicitly convert the text to a date.